# Clonezilla complains that the disk is too small by 3 sectors

Tags: backup, clonezilla

I made an image of my whole drive last night now I need to restore it back. However Clonezilla complaint that the drive is too small by a crazy tiny margin:

```
Destination disk is too small!
Destination disk size: 976773165 sectors (500.1 GB)
Source disk size from the image: 976773168 sectors (500.1 GB)
```

I do not get it. This is the exact same drive. Clonezilla also verified that this backup was restorable when I imaged it.

Any recommendations or insights on how to force Clonezilla to make this restoration back?

I have been cloning with Clonezilla for couple years for backup. Now when I need it to use it the first time to restore back, it does not work.

Comment: Maybe you need to do a low-level format of the drive with some LiveCD utility? I've never heard of such a cloning issue before though. Can't wait to see the other responses

Comment: First you must understand size different is greater then 3 bytes.  A sector isn't 1-byte.  I would verify you only have a single partition.  Of course its entirely possible the number of valid sectors has changed by three, if thats the case, your target hdd is no longer big enough for the target data.

Comment: @Ramhound, I made the image last night. The image had multiple partitions, and I imaged the whole drive. How can valid sectors can change if all I did was to try to restore it? I edited the title based on your information

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, what is a good method to do low level format?

Comment: @yaruncan - The firmware on a hdd continiously go through and mark bad sectors. Use your favorite S.M.A.R.T tool to determine if the number of bad sectors is high.

Comment: @Ramhound, ok that is fine but what are my options then?

Comment: Considering the comments above, there might be very little you can do if the firmware has marked the sectors as being bad. The obvious solution is to get a larger hard drive or a different 500GB drive with enough sectors for the restoration. Do you have a big enough external drive that you can restore it to, delete some stuff, re-create image, and restore to original 500GB drive?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, the original drive has a lot of space actually. It was 500gb drive but only 80 Gb was used I think. I do not know why the drive size is important at this point if I have so much empty space. i can see that where the partitions are is important but could not CZ adjust that accordingly?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus,btw we do not know if the issue is a result of bad sectors at this point. It could be CZ thing too. I am investigating.

Comment: @yaruncan I see, does CloneZilla have the option for fixed/automatic proportioning? I was able to do such things with Acronis in the past.

Comment: The funny thing is that I just look at the disk with fdisk and fdisk is reporting it as "255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
" Same as the image sectors.  So CZ is totally confused about the number of sectors on the disk and the number of sectors in the image. At this point I am suspecting that either CZ is confused or there is faulty hardware like bad usb cables or usb adapter. I will try getting new ones and try those.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I found problem was in connection! When I used "DeLOCK Dockingstation SATA HDD > USB 3.0", Clonezilla showed 3 sectors smaller disk!
So I used simple SATA>USB3 cable and Clonezilla showed correct disk size!

So, correct cable solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1230865/cant-back-1tb-disk-up-because-it-is-one-sector-too-short)) and I think there is no solution. 
I always thought that X sectors = Y bytes, thus 1TB should be only one certain amount of sectors. But it turns out, each brand can (and does) manufacture the disk in different real, total size, and they can presumably sell as long as it has **at least** 1TB.

In my case I tried with an external USB disk 'Seagate Expansion' (1TB) as the destination disk and it was **one sector** too short. So I thought, "bad luck" and tried with a 1TB 'WD Elements', and now the sectors count is even more far away from the sectors of my source disk.

So the only solution (if you don't want to try all disks in the market) would be to buy exactly the same disk as the source drive. In my case the source drive is also Western Digital, but probably can't buy it nowadays, so I will have to use a 1.5TB or 2TB if I want to clone sector by sector..